# Hippo CMS 7 CND file not configuring node?

Tags: content-management-system, taxonomy, hippocms

I am trying to install the taxonomy and taxonomy picker plugins for the cms.

I have the following cnd file within my namespaces folder:

myhippoproject.cnd:

```
<'myhippoproject'='http://www.onehippo.org/myhippoproject/nt/1.0'>
<'hippo'='http://www.onehippo.org/jcr/hippo/nt/2.0.2'>
<'hippostd'='http://www.onehippo.org/jcr/hippostd/nt/2.0'>
<'hippostdpubwf'='http://www.onehippo.org/jcr/hippostdpubwf/nt/1.0'>
<'hippotaxonomy'='http://www.hippoecm.org/hippotaxonomy/nt/1.2'>

[myhippoproject:basedocument] > hippo:document, hippostd:publishableSummary,
hippostdpubwf:document orderable

[myhippoproject:textdocument] > myhippoproject:basedocument,
hippostd:relaxed, hippotaxonomy:classifiable

[myhippoproject:newsdocument] > myhippoproject:basedocument,
hippostd:relaxed
```

From what I understand, textdocument should inherit
myhippoproject:basedocument, hippostd:relaxed, and
hippotaxonomy:classifiable when generated. However, when I build the project
and browse to localhost:8080/cms/console, and look at the textdocument node
under myhippoproject, the mixins for those 3 are not ticked.

I also get the error 'node is not classifiable' even after I've manually
ticked the classifiable mixin.

Answer (score 3):

Can you take a look at the namespace for myhippoproject in the cnd export at `localhost:8080/cms/console`. Does it there say `'hippotaxonomy:classifiable'` for you doc types? If not, you most likely need to start with a clean repository (after you rebuild the project of course)